# Discrete math, statements true or false

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

[image: The task at hand]

The universal set defined for the task is $\{2,3,4,5,\dots\}$.

I've been tearing my hair out at this one for quite some time.

I can make the top one true, as in my head you can always just select $n=m$ and $k=1$.

However, the correct answer is apparently **2)**, **3)** and **4)**. I can recognize **2)** as *Fermat's* (?), but beyond that I reckon I'm thinking myself more confused than not.

Any explanations to a lad with an exam in a few days? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem, you are not allowed to use $k=1$, it is not in the universe. So any $n$ that is not a perfect power with exponent $\gt 1$ is a counterexample. The first few are $2,3,5,6,7,10$.

For the third problem, you can take $n=2$. With that choice, the sentence is true, since $m$ and $m^n$ have the same parity.

For the fourth problem, take $k=2$ and $n=5$.

And you are right about the second problem. Given $m\ge 2$, we can find a prime $n$ such that $n$ does not divide $m$. For that prime, the congruence will hold.

Comment: Thank you so much! You cleared it all up for me, - really appreciate it. :-) As to the first one I am currently blushing for chosing $k=1$. If I may ask - do you have any advice as to how to go forth to see these things faster?

Comment: You are welcome. No advice, except to do what you are doing, practice. Formal language is partly new to you, so absorbing the meaning of a sentence can be slow.  Note that in determining truth/falsehood, except for the second problem, we worked quite concretely with small numbers.